# Traversing Google searches using LuaSocket

Tags: lua, luasocket

I am trying to make a Lua program that creates a google search, and formats all of the results in a different arrangement. The only problem is that I cannot find a way to do these:

1. get the html of the search results
2. search through all of the pages
3. search with omitted results on

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [LuaCurl](http://luacurl.luaforge.net/)